# RecyclerView when dragging first item, it jumps to bottom

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, drag

I am using “drag & drop” and “swipe-to-dismiss” in RecyclerView with ItemTouchHelper.  Without any library, according to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.v8swclo40) . It works perfectly.
But the problem occurs when there is scroll in RecyclerView . When I start to drag **first** item down, **first** and **second** elements swap positions, RecyclerView  is scrolled up and the first element(that I am dragging) occurs on bottom before last element(many swipes occure because of RecyclerView scrolling). It happens very fast, so I cannot put first element wherever I want.

**Note that It happens only with first element, also only when dragging down.**

I think this happens because when **second** element goes to position 1, **third** element goes to **second** position and also swipes with **first** element, and the same with other elements, they are all swiped with **first** element. How can I fix this.

This is what is called when first item changes position with second (and also with any dragging when items swap positions). After one swap, one item goes done:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(categories, i, i + 1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(categories, i, i - 1);
            }
        }

        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: I have added the method that is called multiple times after first swap (1 and 2 element) because of scroll. Other code is from the tutorial in link

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem with that tutorial. I searched about that problem and got the answer finally in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992427/recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemmoved0-1-scrolls-screen?answertab=votes#tab-top). For me, second answer worked perfectly. I will upload the code which just connects the tutorial code and the second answer code on the link.

In the Adapter

```
    @Override
    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(categories, i, i + 1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(categories, i, i - 1);
            }
        }

        // AdapterInteractionListener
        mListener.maintainRecyclerViewPosition(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
```

In the Activity/Fragment

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    int firstPos = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    int offsetTop = 0;
    if(firstPos >= 0){
      View firstView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstPos);
      offsetTop = layoutManager.getDecoratedTop(firstView) - layoutManager.getTopDecorationHeight(firstView);
    }

    mItemAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    if(firstPos >= 0) {
      layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(firstPos, offsetTop);
    }
```

Comment: I am also facing this same issue. But this solution is not working for me. Any other idea please?

Answer (score 3):

Just return true in callback:

```
private val itemTouchHelper = object : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
        override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
            val drag = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN or ItemTouchHelper.START or ItemTouchHelper.END
            val swipe = 0
            return makeMovementFlags(drag, swipe)
        }

        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
            val fromPosition = viewHolder.adapterPosition
            val toPosition = target.adapterPosition

            Collections.swap(systemsAdapter?.currentSystems, fromPosition, toPosition)
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)

            return true
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}

        override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled(): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
            return true
        }

    }
```