# Drag & Dropping the first item of the RecyclerView moves several random positions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, drag-and-drop

Currently, I have a RecyclerView implementing the new ListAdapter, using submitList to differ elements and proceed to update the UI automatically.

Lately i had to implement drag & drop to the list using the well known ItemTouchHelper. Here is my implementation, pretty straight forward:

```
class DraggableItemTouchHelper(private val adapter: DestinationsAdapter) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {
private val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
private val swipeFlags = 0

override fun isLongPressDragEnabled() = false
override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled() = false

override fun getMovementFlags(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Int {
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags)
}

override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Boolean {
    val oldPos = viewHolder.adapterPosition
    val newPos = target.adapterPosition

    adapter.swap(oldPos, newPos)
    return true
}

override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
}
```

}

this is my swap function inside the adapter:

```
fun swap(from: Int, to: Int) {
    submitList(ArrayList(currentList).also {
        it[from] = currentList[to]
        it[to] = currentList[from]
    })
}
```

Everything works well EXCEPT when moving the FIRST item of the list. Sometimes it behaves OK, but most of the time (like 90%), it snaps several positions even when moving it slightly above the second item (to move 1st item on 2nd position for example). The new position seems random and i couldn't figure out the issue.

As a guide, i used the https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android example to implement Drag&Drop and for their (simple) list&layout works well. My list is a bit complex since it's inside a viewpager, using Navigation component and having many other views constrained together in that screen, but i don't think this should be related.

At this point i don't even know how to search on the web for this issue anymore.
The closest solution I found for this might be https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37018279 but after implementing and having the same behaviour, I am thinking it's because I use ListAdapter which differs and updates the list asynchronously, when the solution uses RecyclerView.Adapter which uses notifyItemMoved and other similar methods.

Switching to RecyclerView.Adapter is not a solution.

Comment: Same issue here. For me, dragging the first item when there are no items beyond the visible screen space, it works fine. However, dragging it when there are items off screen (the recyclerView is scrollable) then it jumps a number of positions. And it's a pattern, if there is 1 item off screen, the first item jumps 2 positions. If there are 2 items off screen, then it jumps 3 positions, and so on. It has this (n, n+1) behavior where n = number of items off screen. I have verified this pattern on 3 emulators and a physical device. Is this what your experiencing?

Comment: So after more research, I found that the first item isn't snapping, it's that the whole screen is scrolling (in my case all the way down to reveal the last item offscreen, for whatever reason). Although the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992427/recyclerview-adapter-notifyitemmoved0-1-scrolls-screen?answertab=votes#tab-top) didn't help me, they helped others and hopefully you.

Comment: @gig6 I'm experiencing the very same problem. All the details of my problem are just the same as yours. I've been trying to find a way to submit the list to `ListAdapter` without making it inform the `RecyclerView` of changes, so I could do it myself by calling `notifyItemMoved()` (this way it works perfectly). However, I have found no way of achieving that. Maybe I should file a feature request for this though or report a bug that the Diff Util behaves weirdly in the described cases.

Comment: @gig6 I actually managed to find a solution to this: check out my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in `AsyncListDiffer`, which is used under the hood by `ListAdapter`. My solution lets you manually diff changes when you need to. However, it's rather hacky, uses reflection, and may not work with future `appcompat` versions (The version I've tested it with is `1.3.0`).

Since `mDiffer` is private in `ListAdapter` and you need to work directly with it, you'll have to create your own `ListAdapter` implementation(you can just copy the original source). And then add the following method:

```
fun setListWithoutDiffing(list: List<T>) {
    setOf("mList", "mReadOnlyList").forEach { fieldName ->
        val field = mDiffer::class.java.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(mDiffer, list)
    }
}
```

This method silently changes the current list in the underlying `AsyncListDiffer` without triggering any diffing, as `submitList()` would.

The resulting file should look like this:

```
package com.example.yourapp

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AdapterListUpdateCallback
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncDifferConfig
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer.ListListener
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

abstract class ListAdapter<T, VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder?> : RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
    private val mDiffer: AsyncListDiffer<T>
    private val mListener =
        ListListener<T> { previousList, currentList -> onCurrentListChanged(previousList, currentList) }

    protected constructor(diffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>) {
        mDiffer = AsyncListDiffer(
            AdapterListUpdateCallback(this),
            AsyncDifferConfig.Builder(diffCallback).build()
        ).apply {
            addListListener(mListener)
        }
    }

    protected constructor(config: AsyncDifferConfig<T>) {
        mDiffer = AsyncListDiffer(AdapterListUpdateCallback(this), config).apply {
            addListListener(mListener)
        }
    }

    fun setListWithoutDiffing(list: List<T>) {
        setOf("mList", "mReadOnlyList").forEach { fieldName ->
            val field = mDiffer::class.java.getDeclaredField(fieldName)
            field.isAccessible = true
            field.set(mDiffer, list)
        }
    }

    open fun submitList(list: List<T>?) {
        mDiffer.submitList(list)
    }

    fun submitList(list: List<T>?, commitCallback: Runnable?) {
        mDiffer.submitList(list, commitCallback)
    }

    protected fun getItem(position: Int): T {
        return mDiffer.currentList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mDiffer.currentList.size
    }

    val currentList: List<T>
        get() = mDiffer.currentList

    open fun onCurrentListChanged(previousList: List<T>, currentList: List<T>) {}
}
```

Now you need to change your adapter implementation to inherit from your custom `ListAdapter` rather than `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`.

Finally you'll need to change your adapter's `swap()` method implementation to use the `setListWithoutDiffing()` and `notifyItemMoved()` methods:

```
fun swap(from: Int, to: Int) {
    setListWithoutDiffing(ArrayList(currentList).also {
        it[from] = currentList[to]
        it[to] = currentList[from]
    })
    notifyItemMoved(from, to)
}
```

---

An alternative solution would be to create a custom `AsyncListDiffer` version that lets you do the same without reflection, but this way seems easier. I will also file a feature request for supporting manual diffing out of the box and update the question with a Google Issue Tracker link.

Answer (score 0):

I kept a copy of the items in my adapter, modified the copy, and used `notifyItemMoved` to update the UI as the user was dragging. I only save the updated items/order AFTER the user finishes dragging. This works for me because 1) I had a fixed length list of 9 items; 2) I was able to use `clearView` to know when the drag ended.

**ListAdapter - kotlin:**

```
var myItems: MutableList<MyItem> = mutableListOf()

fun onMove(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int): Boolean {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
            Collections.swap(myItems, i, i + 1)
        }
    } else {
        for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
            Collections.swap(myItems, i, i - 1)
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
    return true
}
```

**ItemTouchHelper.Callback() - kotlin:**

```
// my items are only ever selected during drag, so when selection clears, drag has ended
override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
    // clear drag style after item moved
    viewHolder.itemView.requestLayout()
    // trigger callback after item moved
    val itemViewHolder = viewHolder as MyItemViewHolder
    itemViewHolder.onItemMovedCallback(adapter.myItems)
}
```

**MyItemViewHolder - kotlin**

```
fun onItemMovedCallback(reorderedItems: List<MyItem>) {
    // user has finished drag
    // save new item order to database or submit list properly to adapter
}
```

I also had an `itemOrder` field on MyItem. I updated that field using the index of the re-ordered items when I saved it to the DB. I could probably update each items `itemOrder` field when I swap the items, but it seemed pointless (I just calculate the new order after the drag is finished).

I'm using LiveData from my database. I found the views "flickered" after the final database save because I changed the `itemOrder` on all the items and moved the items around in the adapter list. If this happens to you and you don't like it, just temporarily disable the recycler view item animator (I achieved this by setting it to null after the drag and restoring it after the list is updated in the RecyclerView/Adapter).

This worked for me and my specific case. Let me know if you need more details.